# Delphi XE IB components SQL property editor?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Is there a ready expert which to replace the old and very unconfortable SQL property editor comming with IB components ( like IBQuery ).

Or just point me to creating one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is not a expert but property editor. To create custom property editor you create an designtime package which implements an [`TBasePropertyEditor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DesignIntf.TBasePropertyEditor) descendant and register it using [`RegisterPropertyEditor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DesignIntf.RegisterPropertyEditor) procedure.

Some thirdparty DB components come with custom property editors, but they might not be compatible with the IB components so you probably can't just register them for the IB components. However, if they come with source then you can use them as an exampe as how to implement one. For example the [UIB](http://www.progdigy.com/?page_id=5) components do have custom property editor for SQL, using SynEdit, and as the UIB is open source you can use it as an example.

Comment: thanks Ain. I have edited my question coresponding on what i am really looking for.

Comment: i have completed 1st step based on the idea Ain... thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write your sql elsewhere and paste it into the IB SQL property editor. IB Console, which comes with IB, DB Workbench and others let you do this in a better editor, and in an active database where you can see the results of your sql, change it until you are satisfied with the result, then copy it. For complex sql this may work better.

Comment: nah. i have moved trough the nightmare called "SQL editor" coming with  Delphi. It is not professional work, neither i will even speak about it's bugs.. scrolling .. etc. The main idea is to replace this "thing" with something more profesional looking, because i am reading thoose properties about 500-600 times per day. It is just not an option to copy/paste those text in and back just to test it against some missed symbol. :)

Comment: How much sql are you thinking of putting in the sql property of an IBQuery component? I've never put enough code there to need scrolling. And once it works I don't change it, so pasting is usually a one-time event. You must have something else in mind.